# Can't install glib with brew

Tags: install, homebrew

I'm trying to install gtk+ through brew.  It requires glib as a dependency and brew seems to try and install patches that don't exist?  How can I install glib?

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$ brew install gtk+
Also installing dependencies: glib, jpeg, libtiff, jasper, gdk-pixbuf, pango, atk
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.28/glib-2.28.7.tar.bz2
File already downloaded in /Users/me/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> Downloading patches

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
######################################################################## 100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
/usr/bin/patch: **** Can't open patch file 001-homebrew.diff : No such file or directory
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/patch -f -p0 -i 001-homebrew.diff
My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$
```

***UPDATE***: I had tried to do a `brew update` prior to installing glib, it seemed to go fine, I think...

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$ brew update
Initialized empty Git repository in /usr/local/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 72135, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (35678/35678), done.
remote: Total 72135 (delta 48652), reused 56690 (delta 35657)
Receiving objects: 100% (72135/72135), 10.27 MiB | 436 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (48652/48652), done.
From http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
From http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$ brew -v
0.8
```

I just tried it again, however, for fun and got this response:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$ brew update
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    .gitignore
    Library/Aliases/0mq
    Library/Aliases/4store
    Library/Aliases/Secret Rabbit Code
    Library/Aliases/alut
    Library/Aliases/android
    Library/Aliases/apache-activemq
    Library/Aliases/apache-fop
    Library/Aliases/aws-as
    Library/Aliases/aws-mon
    Library/Aliases/beanstalkd
    Library/Aliases/bjam
    Library/Aliases/bzr
    Library/Aliases/cowthink
    Library/Aliases/cpanm
    Library/Aliases/ctags-exuberant
    Library/Aliases/db
    Library/Aliases/dbus
    Library/Aliases/dejagnu
    Library/Aliases/eyeD3
    Library/Aliases/firefly
    Library/Aliases/fluidsynth
    Library/Aliases/fsa
    Library/Aliases/gearmand
    Library/Aliases/gnu-scientific-library
    Library/Aliases/google-go
    Library/Aliases/gpg
    Library/Aliases/gs
    Library/Aliases/gtk
    Library/Aliases/gtypist
    Library/Aliases/hudson
    Library/Aliases/hugs
    Library/Aliases/ipsum
    Library/Aliases/jocr
    Library/Aliases/jslint
    Library/Aliases/lcms
    Library/Aliases/leg
    Library/Aliases/libcryptopp
    Library/Aliases/libgd
    Library/Aliases/libgeoip
    Library/Aliases/libjpeg
    Library/Aliases/libjpg
    Library/Aliases/liblabjackusb
    Library/Aliases/libmad
    Library/Aliases/libmcrypt
    Library/Aliases/liboggz
    Library/Aliases/libqrencode
    Library/Aliases/libtag
    Library/Aliases/libtasn
    Library/Aliases/littlecms
    Library/Aliases/mc
    Library/Aliases/mongo
    Library/Aliases/mp4box
    Library/Aliases/node.js
    Library/Aliases/nsis
    Library/Aliases/o-caml
    Library/Aliases/ocaml
    Library/Aliases/offlineimap
    Library/Aliases/omake
    Library/Aliases/ooc
    Library/Aliases/openocd
    Library/Aliases/p4
    Library/Aliases/p4d
    Library/Aliases/pipeviewer
    Library/Aliases/pkgconfig
    Library/Aliases/postgres
    Library/Aliases/rbx
    Library/Aliases/ree
    Library/Aliases/saga
    Library/Aliases/shell-fm
    Library/Aliases/slang
    Library/Aliases/stax-sdk
    Library/Aliases/style
    Library/Aliases/svn
    Library/Aliases/umfpack
    Library/Aliases/urxvt
    Library/Aliases/usb-multiplex-daemon
    Library/Aliases/zmq
    Library/Contributions/brew_bash_completion.sh
    Library/Contributions/brew_fish_completion.fish
    Library/Contributions/brew_zsh_completion.zsh
    Library/Contributions/manpages/brew.1.md
    Library/Formula/a2ps.rb
    Library/Formula/a52dec.rb
    Library/Formula/aacgain.rb
    Library/Formula/aalib.rb
    Library/Formula/aamath.rb
    Library/Formula/aardvark_shell_utils.rb
    Library/Formula/abcde.rb
    Library/Formula/abiword.rb
    Library/Formula/abnfgen.rb
    Library/Formula/abook.rb
    Library/Formula/ace.rb
    Library/Formula/ack.rb
    Library/Formula/activemq.rb
    Library/Formula/adns.rb
    Library/Formula/adobe-air-sdk.rb
    Library/Formula/adplug.rb
    Library/Formula/advancecomp.rb
    Library/Formula/aescrypt.rb
    Library/Formula/afflib.rb
    Library/Formula/afsctool.rb
    Library/Formula/aften.rb
    Library/Formula/aget.rb
    Library/Formula/aggregate.rb
    Library/Formula/aircrack-ng.rb
    Library/Formula/aldo.rb
    Library/Formula/algol68g.rb
    Library/Formula/alpine.rb
    Library/Formula/android-ndk.rb
    Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
    Library/Formula/ansifilter.rb
    Library/Formula/antiword.rb
    Library/Formula/antlr.rb
    Library/Formula/aoeui.rb
    Library/Formula/apachetop.rb
    Library/Formula/apg.rb
    Library/Formula/apgdiff.rb
    Library/Formula/aplus.rb
    Library/Formula/app-engine-java-sdk.rb
    Library/Formula/appswitch.rb
    Library/Formula/aqbanking.rb
    Library/Formula/arabica.rb
    Library/Formula/aria2.rb
    Library/Formula/arm.rb
    Library/Formula/arp-sk.rb
    Library/Formula/arping.rb
    Library/Formula/arpoison.rb
    Library/Formula/arss.rb
    Library/Formula/ascii.rb
    Library/Formula/asciidoc.rb
    Library/Formula/asn1c.rb
    Library/Formula/aspell.rb
    Library/Formula/astyle.rb
    Library/Formula/asymptote.rb
    Library/Formula/aterm.rb
    Library/Formula/atf.rb
    Library/Formula/atk.rb
    Library/Formula/atlassian-plugin-sdk.rb
    Library/Formula/atomicparsley.rb
    Library/Formula/atool.rb
    Library/Formula/audiofile.rb
    Library/Formula/authexec.rb
    Library/Formula/auto-scaling.rb
    Library/Formula/autobench.rb
    Library/Formula/autoconf-archive.rb
    Library/Formula/autogen.rb
    Library/Formula/autojump.rb
    Library/Formula/automoc4.rb
    Librar
Aborting
Error: Failure while executing: git checkout -q master 
My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$
```

Tried that several times..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a `brew update` before re-attempting the install.

Similar problem, which was solved by an update, was reported [on github](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/8907).

Comment: I updated the question with a response.  Is 0.8 the latest version?

Comment: Installed fresh, I get version 0.9.2.  I also note that the `brew update` error you got was seen last year (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/5128) due to a git update, with a fix suggested (`cd /usr/local; git fetch origin; git reset --hard origin/master`) -- but I think a newer brew should take care of it.

Comment: Thanks!  That resolved everything!  I had to run `git remote add origin git://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git` after `cd`'ing to `/usr/local`, but otherwise I was then at brew 0.9.2 and able to install glib and gtk+.